# Batch Script to delete older folders with yyyymm as folder name

Tags: batch-file

I have folders named like this 201601,201501,201602,201603 , basically yyyymm as the folder name.

Considering for today's month the folder will be 201606. I need to delete all the folders which are 6 months older than 201606.

Also, I don't want to delete the folders by the modified date but by checking the month and year in the folder name and comparing it with current month's folder year and month and delete if the folder is more than 6 months old.

Comment: "_I need to delete all the folders which are 6 months older than 201606_"  long time to that happen :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it in batch:

```
echo off

SET rootdir=C:\Temp
SET yyyy=%date:~10,4%
SET cmm=%date:~4,2%

::calculate name of folder 6 months ago based on current month:
if %cmm%==01 (SET /a yyyy=%yyyy%-1 && SET mm=07)
if %cmm%==02 (SET /a yyyy=%yyyy%-1 && SET mm=08)
if %cmm%==03 (SET /a yyyy=%yyyy%-1 && SET mm=09)
if %cmm%==04 (SET /a yyyy=%yyyy%-1 && SET mm=10)
if %cmm%==05 (SET /a yyyy=%yyyy%-1 && SET mm=11)
if %cmm%==06 (SET /a yyyy=%yyyy%-1 && SET mm=12)
if %cmm%==07 (SET mm=01)
if %cmm%==08 (SET mm=02)
if %cmm%==09 (SET mm=03)
if %cmm%==10 (SET mm=04)
if %cmm%==11 (SET mm=05)
if %cmm%==12 (SET mm=06)

::move to target directory:
pushd %rootdir%

::remove old folders:
for /D %%a in (*) do (
    if %%a LSS %yyyy%%mm% (rmdir /s /q %%a)
)
::return to current directory (optional):
popd
```

But it's way easier in PowerShell:

```
$rootdir = "C:\Temp\"
$yyyymm = get-date -Date (get-date).AddMonths(-6) -Format "yyyyMM"
Get-ChildItem $rootdir -Directory | Where-Object {$_.Name -lt $yyyymm} | Remove-Item
```